# cin en array en c++

Tags: c++

como puedo introducir datos en un array de ints desde el cin?

```
int leer[5];

cin>>leer;
```

Comment: *Tengo algo asi*, debes colocar lo que tienes.

Comment: arreglado ^.^ .

Comment: ¿Cual es su pregunta? es *como puedo introducir datos en un array de chars desde el cin?* o  *como puedo hacer que el usuario pueda seleccionar una opcion?*, recuerde que SO es un lugar para una pregunta por post, por ello el boton dice **Formular una pregunta**, no dice **Formular preguntas**

Comment: tienes razón, corregido.

Comment: ¿Quieres ingresar chars o un string?

Comment: ingresar numeros* ha sido un error.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes un array tal que:

```
int leer[5];
```

Una forma de rellenarlo a partir de datos del usuario podría ser:

```
for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
  std::cin >> leer[i];
```